# how i can send the selected option from the database to the server in php

Tags: php, html

i have this form who get the values from the user and database(select tag)

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="ajoutement2.php">
        <label class="sr-only" for="Nom_de_la_Categorie2">Nom de la Catégorie</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Nom_de_la_Categorie2" placeholder="Nom de la Catégorie" required autofocus><br>
        <select class="custom-select">
            <option disabled selected>sélectionnez la catégorie supérieure</option>
            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($reponse1)):;?>
            <option><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </select><br><br>
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Ajouter"></form?
```

and i want to get the value of the selected option(in the select tag) to use later

Comment: Very crude answer but give your <select> element a name attribute then read it in your PHP script. `<select name="foo"...>`, ajoutement2.php -> `<?php echo $_POST['foo']; ?>`

Comment: thank you mate its my first time using database in select tag i used to put value attribute in the option tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```html
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="ajoutement2.php">
  <label class="sr-only" for="Nom_de_la_Categorie2">Nom de la Catégorie</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Nom_de_la_Categorie2" placeholder="Nom de la Catégorie" required autofocus><br>
  <select class="custom-select" name="foo">
    <option disabled selected>sélectionnez la catégorie supérieure</option>
    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($reponse1)):;?>
    <option>
      <?php echo $row1[1];?>
    </option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
  </select><br><br>
  <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Ajouter">
</form>
```

PHP:

inside your PHP file `ajoutement2.php`, you can get the select value by using `$_POST['foo']`, something like:

```
$parentCategory = $_POST['foo'];
```